# About implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char', why it is different between `s[i] += s[j]` and `s[i] = s[i]+s[j] `

Tags: c#

The sample code for demo:

```
public void ReverseString(char[] s) {
  for(int i = 0, j = s.Length-1; i < j; i++, j--){
        //s[i] = s[i]+s[j]; //<-- error           
        s[i] += s[j];       //<-- ok 

        s[j] = (char)(s[i] - s[j]); //<-- cast
        s[i] -= s[j];
    }
}
```

As the above code snippet, while `s[i] += s[j]` is fine without any error. Its equivalent statement `s[i] = s[i]+s[j]` will cause error as follows

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

My question is what's their difference and why. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eric Lippert's [Compund assignment post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one/) does a good job of explaining it. (If you want to skip directly to the relevant bit, search the page for `explicit`. That paragraph onwards...)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Its equivalent statement `s[i] = s[i]+s[j]` will cause error as follows

It's not an equivalent statement, although I can understand why you'd expect it to be. From [section 12.18.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=236&zoom=100,0,797) of the C# 5 ECMA standard, around compound assignment:

> An operation of the form `x op= y` is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution (§12.4.5)
>   as if the operation was written `x op y`. Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is
>     evaluated as `x = x op y`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator
>     is explicitly convertible to the type of `x`, and if `y` is implicitly convertible to the type of `x` or the
>     operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x op y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.

That second bullet is what's happening here. There's no operator to add `char` values together - what there *is* is an `int +(int, int)` operator, which is what's selected - and there's an explicit conversion from `int` to `char`.

So this:

```
s[i] += s[j];
```

is more equivalent to

```
s[i] = (char) (s[i] + s[j]);
```

... which compiles fine.